# WearOS app closes on AVD when modifying sensors values

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, android-sensors

Good afternoon, I am designing an application that must continuously read the information from the heart rate sensor. Right now all I have done is getting the sensor and linking it to a listener. The problem is that when I modify the value of any sensor (heart rate sensor or not) from the virtual sensors menu, the app closes but it doesn't show any kind of error or crash.

What can be happening?

This is the code I have:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), SensorEventListener{
    private lateinit var mSensorManager: SensorManager
    private var htSensor: Sensor? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            //mainScreen("ID usuario")
        }

        checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS, 100);

        mSensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        htSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        if (htSensor != null){
            println("Heart rate sensor found")
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, htSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
        }else
        {
            println("No heart rate sensor found")
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(p0: SensorEvent?) {
        print("Sensor changed")

    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {
        print("Accuracy changed")
    }

    fun checkPermission(permission: String, requestCode: Int) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity, permission)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
        ) {
            // Requesting the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
        }
    }
}
```

I have even tried to use the default compose activity that Android Studio creates and modify the value of the sensors from the virtual sensors menu and the app is also minimised.